# SQL Server - Bit data type matches String 'True' and 'False'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, boolean, bit

I'm not sure if something special has been done with the database that I am working with, but while optimizing old code, I came across the following (sanitized) query:

```
SELECT Code
FROM GovernmentThing
WHERE IsGovernment = 'True'
```

I checked the data type for `IsGovernment`, assuming that it was a `varchar(5)` or something similar, only to discover that it was a `bit` field.

I then assumed that the code was bad, and checked by running a query returning the `IsGovernment` field. To my great surprise, I discovered that the query was returning only rows where `IsGovernment` was set to 1! Since I then wondered what a check against a string literal `'False'` would return, I tested, just to find that only zero values were returned!!

It is possible that I missed something somewhere in the TSQL updates, or that there is some tricky configuration that makes this work, but... I've never heard of this before.

Can someone please enlighten me - is this documented somewhere, or ???

SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the  excerpt from the [bit data type documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql) that describes this behavior:

> The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE
>   is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, right, I would expect the string conversion to bit to work either implicitly or explicitly using `CAST` or `CONVERT`.